# NSString: how to change file.png to file_320.png without know its suffix ".png"?

Tags: nsstring

I need to create NSString for file name based on screen width, if the file is fixed to be a PNG file, I can do:

```
[filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@"_320.png"]
```

but the file may not be PNG file, so I need a more general way to add a "_320" to file name regardless of its extension, how do I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* ext = [filename pathExtention];
[[filename stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingPathExtension: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"_320%@", ext]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"_320."]

Comment: Thanks, does it work if other part of the string contains dot "."? I'm sure the file name is an URL address.

Comment: No, I assumed from your question it was always just a pure filename.  If this is for modifying a full url you could find the last occurrence of then "." and base it off that.

Comment: [@"url.blah.com/file.png" rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];